# Keyboard input cover when typing

Tags: cordova

I am developing a hybrid application that use the cord over the html5 + jquery and I'm having a problem. When I click the text field to enter something automatic keyboard event is triggered and the keypad is positioned on top of my inputs .

Ideally to click some input appears a keyboard size div to enable the skidding to see what you're typing .

How should I handle this ? Is there any function that does this automatically , or should I program something ? If so, how do such a feat ?

Thanks in advance already .

Comment: can you post your code??

Comment: @AnandJain I'm dont have code.